# If a device's electrical requirements give a voltage range and fixed current, does the current limit assume the lowest input voltage?

Tags: input, standard

I am working with some small devices and checking input power requirements. Many of the standard labels look like this:

> Input Power: 100 - 240 VAC, 50-60Hz, 2.5A

I am trying to determine how much current will be used with 120V or 240V. Because the input voltage is a range of 100 - 240, I am guessing that the device will only pull 2.5A for an input of 100V. Can I assume that for 240V, the maximum current it will draw is 1.0A? There is no documentation on total Watts.

100V * 2.5A = 250W

250W/240V = 1.04A at 240V

UPDATE: Another way to ask this question is how many Watts does this device use? Is it 100V * 2.5A = 250W? Is it 240V * 2.5A = 600W? Does the power vary based on changing the input voltage or will it automatically use less current to maintain the same power? I would like to connect multiple devices to 1 power source

Comment: You'll need to take a look at the efficiency curve of the converter inside the device to find out for sure.  Your calculations will be *roughly* correct, but the converter will usually vary a few % efficiency over the whole input voltage range, with usually a steep drop at the low end.

Comment: I think that "Can I assume that for 240V, the maximum current it will draw is 1.0A?" is an interesting question which is not adequately answered by the answers on the supposed duplicate question.

Comment: Just a guess, but the 2.5A probably is a promise that it won't draw any more than that amount of current under any non-fault circumstance.

Comment: What type of 'small devices' are you looking at?

Comment: @BruceAbbott They are laboratory instruments. Things that heat, shake, vacuum, etc. One specific device is this [centrifuge](https://bionexsolutions.com/hig-centrifuge/). There is also a PC, which is the [Dell optiplex 7490](https://dl.dell.com/topicspdf/optiplex-7490-aio_owners-manual2_en-us.pdf)

Comment: Centrifuge specs: 100–127/200-240 V~, 12/6.2A: 50/60 Hz = **different** current ratings for 110 and 230 V. Not a good example.

Comment: @BruceAbbott This [Plate Labeler](https://www.agilent.com/cs/library/usermanuals/Public/G5404-90003_R02_LabelerUG_P_EN.pdf) is another example. The power reqs are on pg. 34 of the manual.